# Clion "Bundled Cmake does not work in this enviroment" ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, c++, c

I used Eclipse CDT for college lectures, but today I found the solution for C/C++ by JetBrains.

But I can't compile because I don't know how to set the compiler.

[image]

Comment: from your screenshot I see that you are using cmake. Did you install it? If not run `sudo apt-get install cmake` Also make sure that you have g++ on your system and gdb. `sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb cmake`

Comment: yes, I installed both (cmake and gdb cmake) :)

Comment: Okay, I didn't use clion but take a look [on this site](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set the compiler used:

click the menu item 'project'

click the resulting pull down menu items 'properties'

in the resulting properties window

left column click c/c++ Build

in the resulting list click `settings`

in the third column enter the command for the desired compiler

in the second column click the desired compiler

in the resulting list click each entry and set the desired values

similar steps need to be performed for the desired linker